# Using amp-video-iframe inside section tag with subscriptions-section causes error

Tags: reactjs, amp-html

I get this error: `<amp-video-iframe> does not allow tracking iframes. Please use amp-analytics instead.` when an amp-video-iframe is nested in `section subcriptions-section="content"`.  The video will not render.

I don't completely understand how subscriptions-section is used on amp pages, but, I believe, we need to have it present and definitely need to use an amp-video-iframe.  Is there a way around this?

```
<section subscriptions-section="content">
  <amp-video-iframe 
    layout="responsive         
    width="16"
    height="9"
    src="iframe.html"
    poster=""
    >
  </amp-video-iframe>
 </section>
```